Flutter Setup: Android Toolchain Issues - cmdline-tools Missing and License Status Unknown
I'm currently setting up Flutter for Android development, but I'm running into some issues with the Android toolchain. When I run flutter doctor, I get the following warnings:
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/to/windows-android-setup for more details.

Any help or guidance on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

How to install cmdline-tools

Open android studio
At the menu select Tools > SDK Manager
Then go to SDK Tools tab
Find and check Android SDK Command-Line Tools (latest)



Then click apply and ok

How to accept SDK Licenses

Open cmd/terminal
Run flutter doctor --android-licenses
Then accept all licenses

And last check again flutter doctor.
